# Which font is this? (image attached inside)

Tags: fonts

Someone please help me in finding the name of the following font:

Note: Only letters, `ABHM` are displayed.

[image]

Comment: I think it's the wrong place where to ask these type of questions. However, try dafont forum at http://www.dafont.com/forum/

Comment: The closest I got is [Gubblebum](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jelloween/gubblebum/)

Comment: You can always try the online font identification service: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/. However, I tried it with the above image without any positive result.